# Where to copy algpseudocode.sty package

Tags: texstudio

I am totally new to LaTeX. Let me tell my problem.

I have installed TexStudio, after that I took thesis template and editing it using textstudio.

If I want to write pseudo code in my template I have downloaded algpseudocode.sty and copied to template, where min.tex is located. But I am getting the "can be used only in preamble error" in editor. Do I need to copy this file somewhere in textstudio or anywhere else?

I am using windows7.

I am testing with the following code

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The Error:

```
Can be used only in preamble. \usepackage
Environment algorithm undefined. \begin{algorithm}
Package caption Error: \caption outside float \caption
Environment algorithmic undefined. \begin{algorithmic}
Undefined control sequence \Procedure
Undefined control sequence \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment
Undefined control sequence \State
Undefined control sequence \While
Undefined control sequence \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment
Undefined control sequence \State
Undefined control sequence \State
Undefined control sequence \State
Undefined control sequence \EndWhile
Undefined control sequence \State
Undefined control sequence \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment
Undefined control sequence \EndProcedure
\begin{document} ended by \end{algorithmic}. \end{algorithmic}
\begin{document} ended by \end{algorithm}. \end{algorithm}
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Difference (3) between bookmark levels is greater (hyperref) than one, level fixed
```

Comment: Post some code instead. Plus, you should no download packages like `algpseudocode` by hand, have your package manager install it for you.

Comment: That is not a LaTeX document. Where is the document class and preamble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles just fine. Note that the `algorithm` package is needed as well as it provides the `algorithm` environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine after adding the following packages in main.tex.           "\usepackage{algpseudocode}"
"\DeclareCaptionType{algorithm}"